# Web development workflow using Github and Docker

Tags: docker, github, web, workflow

I learnt the basics of github and docker and both work well in my environment. On my server, I have project directories, each with a docker-compose.yml to run the necessary containers. These project directories also have the actual source files for that particular app which are mapped to virtual locations inside the containers upon startup.

My question is now- how to create a pro workflow to encapsulate all of this? Should the whole directory (including the docker-compose files) live on github? Thus each time changes are made I push the code to my remote, SSH to the server, pull the latest files and rebuild the container. This rebuilding of course means pulling the required images from dockerhub each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the whole directory (including the docker-compose files) live on github?

It is best practice to keep all source code including dockerfiles, configuration ... versioned. Thus you should put all the source code, dockerfile, and dockercompose in a git reporitory. This is very common for projects on github that have a docker image.

> Thus each time changes are made I push the code to my remote, SSH to the server, pull the latest files and rebuild the container

Ideally this process should be encapsulated in a CI workflow using a tool like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/). You basically push the code to the git repository, 
which triggers a jenkins job that compiles the code, builds the image and pushes the image to a docker registry.

> This rebuilding of course means pulling the required images from dockerhub each time.

Docker is smart enough to cache the base images that have been previously pulled. Thus it will only pull the base images once on the first build.

Comment: Ah, I see. I will investigate Jenkins asap. Just help me understand that part a bit clearer.  Is it indeed an image that Jenkins creates, or does it take my docker-compose file and create the relevant containers based on the specified images?

Comment: @user3064874 It can do both. You can create a compilation job that compiles code and build the image. You cnan also create a second job (or in same job) that deploys the docker image and start the container. You can configure jenkins 
to do any of these and build custom workflows.